# How to use a variable in quotes in r?

Tags: r

```
q=c('01','02','03')
url="example.com/date=q[1]"
url
# [1] "example.com/date=q[1]"
```

What I really want `url` to be is "example.com/date=01".

What should I do?

Comment: Look into the `paste` and/or `paste0` functions.  There are many other ways to do this but that's probably the most basic way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could for example use either `paste0` or `sprintf`;

`paste0` for simple concatenation;

```
url <- paste0("example.com/date=", q[1])
url
# [1] "example.com/date=01"
```

...or `sprintf` for somewhat more powerful formatting where you could insert the parameter's value anywhere inside the string;

```
url <- sprintf("example.com/date=%s", q[1])
url
# [1] "example.com/date=01"
```

...and - of course since q is a vector - you could transform all urls at once if you want using either technique;

```
urls <- sprintf("example.com/date=%s", q)
urls
# [1] "example.com/date=01" "example.com/date=02" "example.com/date=03"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use paste().

like that:

```
> q=c('01','02','03')
> url <- paste("example.com/date=q[",q[1],"]",sep="")
> url
[1] "example.com/date=q[01]"
```